# Why does the material preview disappears when I activate Tab 'Active Tool' -> 'Workspace' -> 'Filter Add-ons'?

Tags: materials, 3d-view

Why does the material preview disappears when I activate Tab 'Active Tool' -> 'Workspace' -> 'Filter Add-ons'?
I'm working with Blender 3.61

[image: material preview visible, Filter Add-ons not active]

[image: material preview disappeared, Filter Add-ons is active]

Comment: Because you are by default disabling the Cycles Render addon, which in turn disables all its functionality, including previews

Comment: This is it - quite cryptic..

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos this is an answer. Please post it as such.